# Drill down SSRS: hide columns based on drill down in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Before drill down summary report:

[image]

After drill down :

[image]

I have tried this and not able to hide project Name column,it should show only when I drill down the human resource fields.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an workaround for this. However ProjectName Column heading will not be visible in this case.

The following is the process.

1) Remove the column heading of ProjectName (only text keep column as it is).
2) Merge 1st and 2nd column headings and for the group as well.

Now it looks as follows in design mode:

[image: 1st Image]

It will show as no column visible for Project name but data is visible once we expand the group.

output will be shown as follows:

[image: 2nd Image]

Comment: thanks,but i need the column name to be displayed after drilldown.